# Get a URL's Kwargs

Tags: django

Given a URL for example:

```
url(r'^article/(?P<article_id>\d+)/review/(?P<review_id>\d+)/rate/$', views.rate_reviewer,
    name='review_rate_reviewer')
```

Is there a way in django that I could get a list of the Kwargs this URL required eg. ['article_id', 'review_id']?

Comment: Maybe `resolve()` could help? [Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve)

Answer (score -1):

Your view function signature should be:

```
def rate_reviewer(request, article_id, review_id):
    #custom logic where you can use article_id and review_id
    rate_article(article_id, review_id)
```

Other than that you could of course request url like:

```
http:localhost:8000/review_article?article_id=7&review_id=15....
```

and inside view function access these arguments with

```
def rate_reviewer(request):
    article_id=request.GET.get("article_id",None)
    review_id = request.GET.get("review_id", None)
```

You can access all arguments in GET request with request.GET (in POST request it's request.POST), and here you will get dictionary with all input parameters.